# How do I write a bash script to replace words in files and then rename files?

Tags: linux, bash, replace, file-rename

I have a folder structure, as shown below:

[image]

I need to create a bash script that does 4 things:

1. It searches all the files in the generic directory and finds the string 'generic' and makes it into 'something'
2. As above, but changes "GENERIC" to "SOMETHING"
3. As above, but changes "Generic" to "Something"
4. Renames any filename that has "generic" in it with "something"

Right now I am doing this process manually by using the search and replace in net beans. I dont know much about bash scripting, but i'm sure this can be done. I'm thinking of something that I would run and it would take "Something" as the input.

Where would I start? what functions should I use? overall guidance would be great. thanks.

I am using Ubuntu 10.5 desktop edition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Editing

The substitution part is a `sed` script - call it `mapname`:

```
sed -i.bak \
    -e 's/generic/something/g' \
    -e 's/GENERIC/SOMETHING/g' \
    -e 's/Generic/Something/g "$@"
```

Note that this will change words in comments and strings too, and it will change 'generic' as part of a word rather than just the whole word.  If you want just the word, then you use end-word markers around the terms: `'s/\<generic\>/something/g'`.  The `-i.bak` creates backups.

You apply that with:

```
find . -type f -exec mapname {} +
```

That creates a command with a list of files and executes it.  Clearly, you can, if you prefer, avoid the intermediate `mapname` shell/sed script (by writing the `sed` script in place of the word `mapname` in the `find` command).  Personally, I prefer to debug things separately.

#### Renaming

The renaming of the files is best done with the `rename` command - of which there are two variants, so you'll need to read your manual.  Use one of these two:

```
find . -name '*generic*' -depth -exec rename   generic something   {} +

find . -name '*generic*' -depth -exec rename s/generic/something/g {} +
```

*(Thanks to [Stephen P](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17300/stephen-p) for pointing out that I was using a more powerful Perl-based variant of `rename` with full Perl regexp capacity, and to [Zack](https://stackoverflow.com/users/388520/zack) and [Jefromi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/119963/jefromi) for pointing out that the Perl one is found in the real world<sup>*</sup> too.)*

Notes:

- This renames directories.
- It is probably worth keeping the `-depth` in there so that the contents of the directories are renamed before the directories; you could otherwise get messages because you rename the directory and then can't locate the files in it (because `find` gave you the old name to work with).
- The more basic `rename` will move `./generic/do_generic.java` to `./something/do_generic.java` only.  You'd need to run the command more than once to get every component of every file name changed.

---

<sup>*</sup> The version of `rename` that I use is adapted from code in the 1st Edition of the Camel book.

Comment: My `man 1 rename` says it would be simply `rename generic something {}` without the `s///` syntax.

Comment: oh awesome, you've put everything I need in here I see. Thank you so much.

Comment: I believe that Debian-based distros come with the perl-based rename, while the Red Hat extended family tends to use the more basic one, so someone trying to use these instructions might need either syntax. (For what it's worth, I love the fancy perl regex one, and it's just a simple script you can drop into a local bin directory if you're somewhere without it.)

Comment: +1 Nice! Debian-based systems have the Perl script as `rename` and the other one as `rename.ul` (if you install `util-linux`).

Answer (score 1):

Steps 1-3 can be done like this:

```
find .../path/to/generic -type f -print0 |
    xargs -0 perl -pi~ -e \
        's/\bgeneric\b/something/g; 
         s/\bGENERIC\b/SOMETHING/g;
         s/\bGeneric\b/Something/g;'
```

I don't understand exactly what you want to happen in step 4 so I can't help with that part.

Comment: Oh I want to trawl through each directory, find files that contain "generic" in their file name and then change them to whatever the "something" input is..

Comment: It's the "change them" part I don't get.  Do you want a file named 'foo/genericbar.xxx' renamed to 'foo/somethingbar.xxx'?  What about 'generic/foo/bar.xxx'?  'unrelated/directory/generic.xxx'? And do you want a move, or a copy?

Comment: It's a general renaming of the files - and directories.  The `find` command will be scoped to limit the changes to the areas of the file hierarchy where the change is applicable.